# Read a part of directory name and get rid of carriage control usind sed or similar

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, awk

In some script, it reads the directory name and get things like

```
66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/
```

I need to extract the thing "ABC3" so I try

```
    sed -i -e "s/_/ /g" temp_direc
```

so I get

```
66.9090 89.4450 168.0250 ABC3/
```

and then

```
read LABEL <<< $(awk '{print $4}' temp_direc)
```

and now I get

```
ABC3/
```

but I do not know how to remove the final "/". Furthermore, I need later to do this

```
echo $A" "$LABEL
```

being $A some string like 45.56

and I would like the output to be

```
45.56 ABC3
```

but I really get

```
 ABC3/6
```

so it seems the carriage control character is somehow embedded there. How could I get rid of this and get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplier:

```
echo '66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/' | cut -d"_" -f4 | cut -d"/" -f1
```

which yields `ABC3`

Comment: it looks good but when I do; echo "   45    "$var , where $var is obtained with your solution, I get; ABC3 45

Comment: Strange...can you try `echo "'$var'"` and see if anything special besides `ABC3` is printed? You may also try `echo " 45 $var"`

Answer (score 3):

A pure `sed` solution would be:

```
sed 's#.*_\([^_/]*\)\(/\|$\)#\1#'
```

resp. with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's#.*_([^_/]*)(/|$)#\1#'
```

I chose the `#` as a delimiter (instead of the usual `/`) because there's a `/` in the pattern which otherwise would have to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're after here. But to get the ABC3 you have 90% of it already:

```
$echo '66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/' | awk -F'_' '{print $4;}' | sed 's/\///'
ABC3
```

Answer (score 1):

An awk only solution:

```
read LABEL <<< $( echo '66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/' \
                  | awk -F '[_/]' '{printf("%s", $4);}' )
```

Opss ... I supposed that the field is ever the forth, the following line has not this limitation:

```
read LABEL <<< $( echo '66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/' \
                  | awk -F '[_/]' '{printf("%s", $(NF -1));}' ) ; echo $LABEL
```

Answer (score 1):

To get output like `ABC3/6` indicates your `$A` ends with a carriage return. You can use something like `dos2unix` on your input file, or use `tr` to remove the carriage returns:

```
A=$'45.56\r'
B="66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/"

a=$( echo "$A" | tr -d $'\r' )   # remove all carriage returns

b=${B##*_}   # remove up to (and including) the last underscore
b=${b%/}     # remove a trailing slash 

echo "$a $b"  # ==> "45.56 ABC3"
```

Answer (score 1):

> echo '66.9090_89.4450_168.0250_ABC3/'
>   | sed -e 's/^.*_//' -e 's/.$//'